# Package Managers and Custom Installs?

Tags: linux, nginx, yum, apt, package-management

Is it possible to use custom installs in conjunction with the package manager?

For example, I would like to use apt-get to install EngineX because it will also install all the applicable dependencies.

However, I prefer to use version 0.8.34 which I then configure to include modules that EngineX does not come with by default.

Is there some way for me to get the best of both worlds?

**edit:** the main goal for me is to find a way to keep all the dependencies updated

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at checkinstall, which allows to automate the package creation from a fresh compiled application, it can create both .deb and .rpm packages, to use it, just install it and replace the traditional "make install" by "checkinstall". In your case, since you still have installed your app from the repositories, just uninstall the package first (but keep the installed dependencies).

If it doesn't work with your application (this can happen sometimes), you'll have to make your package by yourself, there are many tutorials about this over the web. You can look [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Debian-Binary-Package-Building-HOWTO/) for .deb creation, and [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package) for .rpm creation.

I hope this will help.

Comment: Right now I do all of my installs from source, none from packages. If I created packages from my own installs, how would I be able to keep the dependencies updated?

Comment: to properly handle dependencies (i.e. being able to redistribute packages) you have to build your packages yourself, the tutorials i gave should explain how to configure dependencies while creating packages. checkinstall makes life easy when installing from sources, but it doesn't allow dependecies tracking (or i missed that)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing is not a good practice.  Eventually it will cause you headaches it will definitely cause migraines for anyone who takes over managing these machines if you're no longer there.

You're much better off finding a repository that has the version of the package you're looking for.  As that will track dependencies, allow for easier uninstallation, and allow visibility of what's installed to the package manager.  Google should help you find a repository.  The other option is to learn to build your own packages.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you should start by looking for packages of the version you need, and, failing that building your own packages.

However, there's no reason you can't install the dependencies from apt (or yum), just look for the dependencies (apt-cache show nginx or apt-cache showsrc nginx) and install them.